# 2 Google Maps Conflicting With Each Other

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a web app that has 2 instances of Google Maps API: one which has many points, and one which only has one point.

They seem to be conflicting with each other, because when I view one page before the other, the other map is not centered in the correct spot.

First Page:
[image: first page]
Second Page:
[image: second page]

Here is a link to my project: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B12/index.html

Here is the code that is generating the Google Maps:

```
var detailsMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_" + this.id), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(landmarkList[rowCount].landmarkGPSNorth, landmarkList[rowCount].landmarkGPSWest),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var detailsInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var detailsMarker, j;

detailsMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(landmarksArray[rowCount].landmarkGPSNorth, landmarksArray[rowCount].landmarkGPSWest),
  map: detailsMap,
  icon: "Icons/red-pin.pdf"
});
detailsInfoWindow.setContent(landmarksArray[rowCount].landmarkName);
detailsInfoWindow.open(detailsMap, detailsMarker);

google.maps.event.addListener(detailsMarker, 'click', (function(detailsMarker, j) {
  return function() {
    detailsInfoWindow.open(detailsMap, detailsMarker);
  }
})(detailsMarker, j));
}

document.getElementById("map_" + this.id).style.height = 300 + "px";
document.getElementById("map_" + this.id).style.width = 300 + "px";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Jake. A long ago I'd a similar problem with a Ajax-Based navigation in a website, each page had a map, the first one working normaly, but the next ones had the same problem you're having. What I did was run a ``google.maps.event.trigger(secondMapInstance, 'resize');`` when showing the second map.

Comment: @JoãoMosmann Thanks for your reply. I placed it at the end of the function, and passed detailsMap as the map instance. It is mostly working now, however, it is not centered on the coordinates I set. Is there a function to recenter the map?

Comment: I'll do a more complete answer. Just a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long ago I'd a similar problem with a Ajax-Based navigation in a website, each page had a map, the first one working normally, but the next ones had the same problem you're having.

Before displaying the map you should create a new bound object. Just like this:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

After that. You've to extend the bounds passing your markers positions. Like this:

```
bounds.extend(marker.position);
```

And finally, when the map is actually visible and rendered. Run the following lines.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(secondMapInstance, 'resize');
secondMapInstance.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If there are multiple markers that are on the map (like on the #map screen) should I call bounds.extend each time? or should I only pass in one marker (the closest to the center)?

Comment: Yes, for each marker. So the map will calculate the amount of zoom and   center where all markers are visible.

Comment: Thank you so much. That works perfectly. The last quick question I have, is there any way to control the zoom once the bounds have been fit? or does it zoom to the lowest level?

Comment: I don't know, I just took this code from a old project I have done. But try inspecting the bounds object. Or after setting the bounds, take the current zoom level and change it for the level that better suits your needs.

Please, don't forget to upvote and accept my answer :)